# Accents on Git files

Tags: git, diacritics

When I do `git status` I have something like this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
        new file:   "assets/visio/~$$capteur-r\303\251el.~vsdx"
        new file:   src/40-mesures-multidimensionnelles.tex
        new file:   "src/45-ajustement-mod\303\250le.tex"
        new file:   "src/95-syst\303\250me-de-mesure.tex"

Changes not staged for commit:
        deleted:    "assets/visio/~$$cha\303\256ne-de-mesure.~vsdx"
        modified:   "src/10-syst\303\250me-si.tex"
        modified:   "src/15-cha\303\256ne-de-mesure.tex"
        modified:   "src/20-mod\303\251lisation-cha\303\256ne.tex"
```

Where the weird chars `\303\251` are accents that are not displayed by Git.

However the accents are fine with `ls -al` and my terminal is `UTF-8`.

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color

$ echo $LANG
C.UTF-8

$ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

What's wrong with my Git configuration?

Comment: Post the output of `locale`?

Comment: For reference, `syst\303\250me` is `système` in UTF-8, with the two-byte character represented in octal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The config option that controls this is `core.quotePath` (see the git config docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).  It does not give you much flexibility, but setting it to `false` *might* give you the results you want.